# Grep inside bash script not finding item

Tags: bash, csv

I have a script which is checking a key in one file against a key in another to see if it exists in both. However in the script the `grep` never returns anything has been found but on the command line it does.

```
#!/bin/bash
# First arg is the csv file of repo keys separated by line and in
# this manner 'customername,REPOKEY'
# Second arg is the log file to search through

log_file=$2
csv_file=$1
while read line;
do 
    customer=`echo "$line" | cut -d ',' -f 1`
    repo_key=`echo "$line" | cut -d ',' -f 2`
    if [ `grep "$repo_key" $log_file` ]; then
        echo "1"
    else
        echo "0"
    fi
done < $csv_file
```

The CSV file is formatted as follows:

`customername,REPOKEY`

and the log file is as follows:

REPOKEY

REPOKEY

REPOKEY

etc

I call the script by doing `./script csvfile.csv logfile.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather then checking output of `grep` command use `grep -q` to check its return status:

```
if grep -q "$repo_key" "$log_file"; then
    echo "1"
else
    echo "0"
fi
```

Also your script can be simplified to:

```
log_file=$2
csv_file=$1
while IFS=, read -r customer repo_key; do
    if grep -q "$repo_key" "$log_file"; then
        echo "1"
    else
        echo "0"
    fi
done < "$csv_file"
```

Comment: Hmm, changing this still didn't change my original result, it's like the `grep` isn't working inside the script?

Comment: Just before `grep` insert `echo "[$repo_key]"` and tell me what value do you get

Answer (score 0):

use the exit status of the `grep` command to print `1` or `0`

```
repo_key=`echo "$line" | cut -d ',' -f 2`

grep -q "$repo_key" $log_file

if [ $? -eq 1  ]; then
        echo "1"
    else
        echo "0"
    fi
```

`-q` supresses the output so that no output is printed

`$?` is the exit status of `grep` command  `1` on successfull match and `0` on unsuccessfull

you can have a much simpler version as

```
grep -q "$repo_key" $log_file
echo $?
```

which will produce the same output